# django can't submit comment to database

Tags: python, django, database

I was trying to add a comment function to my django app, but whatever I did, the comment submitted just wouldn't show up in database, can't figure out why. Here're some codes I worked with, please have a look.

the models.py part

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    text = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
        verbose_name="评论"
        verbose_name_plural="评论"

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

---

the forms.py part

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Comment
        fields=('name','email','text')
```

---

the  views.py part

```
def post_comment(request,id):

post=get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)

if request.method=='POST':
    form=CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name=request.POST.get('name','')
        email=request.POST.get('email','')
        text=request.POST.get('text','')
        comment=Comment(name=name,email=email,text=text,post=14)
        comment.save()
        return redirect(post)
    else:
        form=CommentForm()
        comment_list = post.comments.all()
        context={
        'post':post,
        'form':form,
        'comment_list':comment_list
        }
    return render(request,'post_detail.html',context=context)
return redirect(post)
```

---

and the post_detail.html part

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="mb-5">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1">名称</label>
<input name="name" type="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Name">
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">邮箱</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">评论</label>
    <textarea name="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" placeholder="Comment area..." rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="post_comment">提交</button>
    </form>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Well what is `return redirect(post)` supposed to do?

Comment: sorry, I was all confused, didn't know what I was doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing two things wrong here. The first is that you are rendering the form manually and you do not have anything in your HTML to display form errors. You need to add the errors to your HTML as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) - or until yo get this sorted out use `{{ form.as_p }}`

Even after that, it still wont work because your python code in your view is wrong.

```
if form.is_valid():
    name=request.POST.get('name','')
    email=request.POST.get('email','')
    text=request.POST.get('text','')
    comment=Comment(name=name,email=email,text=text,post=14)
    comment.save()
    return redirect(post)
else:
    form=CommentForm()
```

The last two lines of code above results in a new form being created when teh form is invalid. That discards any form data that was posted. Which also means any errors you had will be discarded along the way. The correct code will look something like the following:

```
post=get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)
if request.method=='POST':
    form=CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # don't directly use the request post data. Always use form.cleaned_data        
        name= form.cleaned_data['name'
        .....

        comment=Comment(name=name,email=email,text=text,post=14)
        comment.save()

        # the following redirect is wrong. Here post is an object
        # you retrieved from a database, we usually redirect to a URL
        return redirect(post)

else:
     form = CommentForm()
comment_list = post.comments.all()

context={
        'post':post,
        'form':form,
        'comment_list':comment_list
        }

return render(request,'post_detail.html',context=context)
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed my codes according to your guide, man, I know too little about django.

Answer (score 0):

try this to creating comment class:

```
class Comment(models.Model):

post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
text = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def approve(self):
    self.approved_comment = True
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.text
```

Register Comment model in the admin panel

To register the Comment model in the admin panel, go to blog/admin.py and add this line:

```
admin.site.register(Comment)
```

directly under this line:

```
admin.site.register(Post)
```

Remember to import the Comment model at the top of the file, too, like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Comment)
```

Make our comments visible HTML:

```
<hr>
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
 <div class="comment">
    <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
    <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
    <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
</div>
{% empty %}
<p>No comments here yet :(</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I put the comment function code into the post_detail function, and submit comment to the same page of a post, now it seems to work, hope it's ok.